# How i can logout facebook after published?

Tags: java, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

I have a published button in my web page but i need logout user from facebook after user click in button. How i make it?

---

I try it:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
         //initializing API
         window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: '462904197064938', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml:   true});
        };

        (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>

    <!-- custom login button -->
    <a href="#" onclick="fblogin();return false;">login</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="fblogout();return false;">logout</a>

    <script>
      //your fb login function
      function fblogin() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
          alert("login");
        }, {scope:'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'});
      }

      function fblogout() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
          alert("logout");
        });
      }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

But it not work. The login work fine, but logout not work and not have any error log.
Why it dosent work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook SDK has a logout method that you should be able to use. IIRC, you aren't able to use the GraphAPI to logout.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/.